# How to combine buffered rivers and landcover type in earth engine to get union?

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, union

I want to pull one cover type from an image collection (NLCD) and combine it with buffered river data, a feature collection, with the result being a binary image containing the union or sum of the two.

I'm able to create individual layers that look right for each, but when I try to add them together I'm getting the difference rather than a composite including everything.

```
var roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-95.42728080098401, 48.02069973422627],
          [-95.42728080098401, 47.90897602743195],
          [-95.19553794209729, 47.90897602743195],
          [-95.19553794209729, 48.02069973422627]]], null, false);
var na_river = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/GRN/na_river");
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("USGS/NLCD_RELEASES/2019_REL/NLCD");

// Filter the collection to the 2019 product.
var nlcd2019 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '2019')).first();
// Select the land cover band.
var landcover = nlcd2019.select('landcover');
// get just the open water class and mask all else:
var water = landcover.updateMask(landcover.eq(11));

Map.addLayer(water, {min:0, max:100, palette: ['red']}, 'water'); 

// na_river is a feature collection so we can buffer each image with a mapped function
var buf = na_river.map(function(image){
  var buf = image.buffer(15);
  return buf;
});

Map.addLayer(buf, {min:0, max:100, palette: ['yellow']}, 'river buffer'); 

var foreground = 1;
var background = 0;
var roi_image = ee.Image(background).clip(roi);
var example_image = ee.Image(foreground).clip(buf);
var binary_image = roi_image.where({test:example_image, value:example_image});
var binary_image = binary_image.updateMask(binary_image.eq(1));
print('binary_image:', binary_image);

Map.addLayer(binary_image, {min:0, max:1, palette: ['blue']}, 'binary buffer'); 


var combined_image = binary_image.add(water); // looks like it's giving the difference, rather than the sum

Map.addLayer(combined_image, {min:0, max:12, palette: ['black']}, 'comp_water');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is due to a misunderstanding of how masked pixels work. Similar to "N/A" in any type of calculation, the end result will always be "N/A"; masked pixels will mask the outcome if you use them in a sum, subtraction, etc.

Instead, you need to `.unmask()` your image to turn the masked pixels into a 0 instead of being masked:

```
var combined_image = binary_image.unmask().add(water.unmask());
```

Water also needed to be unmasked.

Comment: When I swap in your line, 'combined_image' returns just the 'water', ie 'binary_image' is missing entirely. Unmasking both and then adding them returns a solid rectangle with the same extent as 'roi'.

Comment: Apologies, you also need to unmask water and then fix your vis parameters when adding to the map (everything is appearing one color because your palette is one color). Here is the updated link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/299d66f103c1650a56133e3d0ac8be52